# Python, import package module when class inherit abstract class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, package, abstract

```
bank
    __init__.py
    Account.py
    SavingAccount.py
main.py
```

The SavingAccount class is inherit from Account(abstract class). When main.py import SavingAccount as below:

from bank.SavingAccount import SavingAccount

It appear "No module named 'Account'". Could someone know how to solve it?

The complete error code in output window as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bank.SavingAccount import SavingAccount
  File "\bank\SavingAccount.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Account import Account
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Account'
```

Acccount.py

```
from abc import ABCMeta,abstractmethod
class Account(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    _id = 0
    _name = ''
    _balance = 0
    __next = 0

    def __init__(self,name,initBal = 1000):
        self._name=name;
        self._balance = initBal
```

SavingAccount.py

```
from Account import Account
class SavingAccount(Account):
    _interestRate = 0

    def __init__(self,name,initBal=0):
        super(SavingAccount,self).__init__(name,initBal)

    @classmethod
    def interestRate(cls):
        _interestRate = 0

    @classmethod
    def interestRate(cls,rate):
        cls._interestRate = rate
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? If you want to import sibling submodules of the same package, you should do it either by absolute import or by *explicit* relative import.

Comment: Python3 with Pycharm

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
from Account import Account
```

to

```
from .Account import Account
```

The latter relative import approach is recommended inside a package.